# websecurityconfigureradapter cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to implement OAuth 2.0 in spring boot application. But the class I need to extend has already been deprecated. And moreover, we can't use authorizeHttpRequests without the customiser in the parameter.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
   http.authorizedRequests()
   .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
   .anyRequest().authenticated()
   .and()
   .oauth2Login();
}
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use new api as below

```
   @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig{
        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            return http.authorizeHttpRequests(c->c
                            .requestMatchers("/").permitAll()
                            .anyRequest().authenticated())
                    .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults())
                    .build();
        }
    }
```