Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig' : Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
I am updating to Java21 and Spring 3.0, when updating my security config to a non deprecated format, i've got the following error:
| ERROR | SpringApplication - Application run failed org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server         at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:164)         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:602)         at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439)         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309)         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298)         at io.inowise.inox.InoxApplication.main(InoxApplication.java:12)         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)         at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)         at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95)         at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)         at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat         at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:142)         at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104)         at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:489)         at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:211)         at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:183)         at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161)         ... 14 common frames omitted Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.beforeSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:355)         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:227)         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:412)         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332)         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162)         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560)         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)         at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.resolveBeanReference(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:362)         at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:334)         at io.inowise.inox.security.SecurityConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.keycloakAuthenticationProvider(<generated>)         at io.inowise.inox.security.SecurityConfig.configureGlobal(SecurityConfig.java:115)         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)         at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:833)         at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145)         at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:492)         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1416)         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597)         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:412)         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332)         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162)         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560)         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)         at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:210)         at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:201)         at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:96)         at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:85)         at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:261)         at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:235)         at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:52)         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4850)         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)         at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:846)         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)         at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:241)         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433)         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:918)         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:485)         at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123)         ... 19 common frames omitted

Here is my security config file:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Value("${cors-allow-origin.url}")
    private String corsAllowOriginUrl;

    @Autowired
    private PermissionService permissionService;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager(http))
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                auth
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                    //Other url's
            });
        return http.build();
    }

    private String[] getRoles(PermissionType permissionType) {
        return permissionService.getRoles(permissionType);
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList(corsAllowOriginUrl.split(",")));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setMaxAge(3600L);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider() {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = new KeycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        return keycloakAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter> keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilterRegistrationBean(KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean<KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter> keycloakPreAuthActionsFilterRegistrationBean(KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean<KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter> keycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilterBean(KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean<KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter> keycloakSecurityContextRequestFilterBean(KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean<KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(HttpSessionManager.class)
    protected HttpSessionManager httpSessionManager() {
        return new HttpSessionManager();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(HeaderBasedConfigResolver.class)
    public org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new HeaderBasedConfigResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakRestTemplate keycloakRestTemplate(KeycloakClientRequestFactory keycloakClientRequestFactory) {
        return new KeycloakRestTemplate(keycloakClientRequestFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class).build();
    }
}

I have tried the old deprecated way of doing it, also the new one with filterChain.
Also when updating the project itself, i've changed all the javax dependencies onto jakarta ones.

See if this question helps, it seems very related  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70581530/error-creating-bean-with-name-securityconfig-requested-bean-is-currently-in-c

i've changed the functions name from configureGlobal to configure, and changed the Autowired to Override, but gives the following error
The method configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder) of type SecurityConfig must override or implement a supertype method
Might be because i am using keycloak instead of another authentication provider?

Maybe you are missing the extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter  ?

I had that on the original SecurityConfig before updating, i dont know if its deprecated or not, but if i keep it i get the error:
WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter cannot be resolved to a type.
I saw that in this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77762795/websecurityconfigureradapter-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type/77762837

Setting spring.main.allow-circular-references=true might help, as a temporary solution
